# Get access to an incrementing integer during LINQ Select

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Dim project = new Project(1)
Dim tasks = Task.GetTasks()
Return <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
                   <Name><%= project.name %></Name>
                   <Tasks>
                       <%= tasks.Select(Function(t) _
                           <Task>
                               <ID><%= tasks.IndexOf(t) + 1 %></ID>                               
                           </Task> _
                           ) %>
                   </Tasks>
               </Project>
```

I am trying to replace `tasks.IndexOf(t) + 1` with something a little simpler. Is there any built in functionality for this?

Hrmm xml literals do not seem to translate well on here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an overload for `Enumerable.Select` that supports passing an index along with the object itself. You can use that one:

```
Dim project = new Project(1)
Dim tasks = Task.GetTasks()
Return <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
                   <Name><%= project.name %></Name>
                   <Tasks>
                       <%= tasks.Select(Function(t, idx) _
                           <Task>
                               <ID><%= idx + 1 %></ID>                               
                           </Task> _
                           ) %>
                   </Tasks>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of `Select` that takes a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` (i.e. a `Function(t,i)` or `(t,i) => {...}`) - the `int` is the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Select overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that uses an indexer.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132618/linq-statement-that-returns-rownumber-of-element-with-id-something/1132689#1132689) for something similar