# Convert SQL to Linq - how to?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Is it possible to convert this SQL to LINQ?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
WITH new AS (
   SELECT [UserSessionSequenceID],
          [SessionGuid],
          SiteID,
          IP,
          UrlTitle,
          Url,
          Referer,
          BrowserWidth,
          BrowserHeight,
          [Timestamp],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SessionGuid]  
                                 ORDER BY UserSessionSequenceID DESC) AS sort  
     FROM [tblSequence] 
    WHERE SiteID = @siteID
      AND [Timestamp] > DATEADD(mi, -@minutes, GETDATE()))
  SELECT TOP(@resultCount) 
         n.* 
    FROM new n
   WHERE n.sort = 1 
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM tblSequence s
                    WHERE s.siteid = n.siteid
                      AND s.sessionguid = n.sessionguid
                      AND [TimeStamp] <= DATEADD(mi, -@minutes, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY n.usersessionsequenceid DESC
            ");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@resultCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resultCount;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@minutes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = minutes;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@siteID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = siteID;
```

I have a class containing all the fields selected from the SQL called "`SimpleSession`". Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I would rather create a View for this statement and use that simple view in Linq2Sql...

Comment: I have my data inMemory now and I simply don't query the DB any longer - so I need to do something else. LINQ :-)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, *many times there isn't no reason to convert complex SQL to some LINQ equivalent* (even in case of compatible statements).

LinqToSql needs to dynamically create the SQL commands when running any LINQ command. *So, do why we would want to overhead if we already know which is the best SQL query to solve?*

**We can easily create LINQ methods that call some View or Stored Procedure and returns it as typed objects**. Your program will continue to be all fully object oriented but without unecessary overheads.

Comment: I have my data inMemory now and I simply don't query the DB any longer - so I need to do something else. LINQ :-)

Answer (score 0):

for first query u can use this

from seq in tblSequence.AsEnumerable()
                         where seq.Field("SiteID") == siteID
                               && seq.Field("Timestamp") > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes)
                         select new
                         {
                             seq.UserSessionSequenceID,
                             seq.SessionGuid,
                             seq.SiteID,
                             seq.IP,
                             seq.UrlTitle,
                             seq.Url,
                             seq.Referer,
                             seq.BrowserWidth,
                             seq.BrowserHeight,
                             seq.Timestamp
                         };

for row_number refer this [How To Project a Line Number Into Linq Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365086/how-to-project-a-line-number-into-linq-query-results/365127#365127)