# SQL: Row_number in linq?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, row-number, sql-to-linq-conversion

This is my sql query, ,

```
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by AirAvail_ID order by AirAvail_ID) as IndexNo,AirAvail_ID from AvailFlt
```

I would like to convert this to LINQ!

O/P:

```
  IndexNo    AirAvail_Id
    1             0
    2             0
    3             0
    4             0
    1             1
    2             1
    3             1
    .             .
    .             .
    .
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Project a Line Number Into Linq Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365086/how-to-project-a-line-number-into-linq-query-results)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365086/how-to-project-a-line-number-into-linq-query-results/365127#365127) is a post on how to project a line number into linq query results

The optimal solution adds the row number on the client side rather than the database side.

Comment: it's not working, can you convert the above query to LINQ?. i'm going to use the linq in vb.net,