# Adding index field to LINQ List <T> results using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using a generic list. For example (with some properties):

```
public class randomList 
{
        public string propertyA { get; set; }
        public string propertyB { get; set; }
        public string propertyC { get; set; }
}
```

So on my retrieving query I used to write the following:

```
_grouppedResto.Select((value, index) => new { index = index, value = value });
dgvHeader.DataSource = _grouppedResto;
```

But now it shows blank on index column. I will like to get something like this :

[image]

this is all about the datagrid :

```
   this.dgvHeader.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dgvHeader.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dgvHeader.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dgvHeader.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dgvHeader.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.FECRGV,
            this.TDORGV,
            this.NDORGV,
            this.RUCCLI,
            this.RAZCLI,
            this.VVTRGVS,
            this.IGVRGVS,
            this.TOTRGVS,
            this.TCARGV,
            this.VVTRGVD,
            this.IGVRGVD,
            this.TOTRGVD});
            this.dgvHeader.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 128);
            this.dgvHeader.Name = "dgvCACD";
            this.dgvHeader.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1265, 611);
            this.dgvHeader.TabIndex = 13;
            **dgvHeader.AutoGenerateColumns = false;**
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't call myself a C# novice, but I can't make much of this question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yea, I'm scratching my head on this one too....

Comment: I don't see any lists in any of the code here.  And "randomList" is a bad class name for two reasons: it's not capitalized correctly, and you should never name a class "SomethingList" if it doesn't implement the IList interface (I think FxCop complains about this one).  As others have said, this question makes no sense at all.

Comment: Since we do not know how you data-bind, it isn't possible to say much here. Judging by _dgv_Header, I'd warrant a guess that you're using WinForms. If so, show all code related to initialization of `dgvHeader` (both `InitializeComponent`, and any of your own in constructor and elsewhere).

Comment: Oh my bad!, why when I edit something then I try to re-edit it again I lost last changes :(

Comment: What is the relation between randomList and _grouppedResto?

Comment: Please also show the code that initializes the _columns_ of your `DataGridView` (it's where the data bindings are).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add an index field to Linq results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to assign _grouppedResto to an anonymous type as in:

```
var yourSequence = _groupedResto.Select((value, index) => new { index = index, value = value });
dgvHeader.DataSource = yourSequence;
```

I'd be happy to help with any particulars you care to provide.
Good luck, hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks for your share your thoughts, btw the datagrid autogeneratecolumns property is set to false, so the datagrid could not generate the columns.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Its always the tiny annoyances that tend to trip me up. Glad to hear you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the index with the properties of your list element you need to change your select statement into something like this:

```
_grouppedResto.Select(
  (value, index) => new {
    index = index, propertyA = value.propertyA, propertyB = value.propertyB
  }
);
```

Comment: Well I think if you make it that way yo need to specify the <T> object after the keyword "new" cause propertyes won't show up...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use this way to solve this... (I think is the worst way, cause you have to modified the domain class)

```
public class RGVCAFAC
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string CODEAUX { get; set; }

        public string FECRGV { get; set; }
        public string TDORGV { get; set; }
        public string MONRGV { get; set; }
        public string NDORGV { get; set; }
        public string RUCCLI { get; set; }
        public string RAZCLI { get; set; }
        public string CDCRGV { get; set; }
        public string TERRGV { get; set; }
        public string PDSRGV { get; set; }
        public double VVTRGVS { get; set; }
        public double IGVRGVS { get; set; }
        public double TOTRGVS { get; set; }
        public string TCARGV { get; set; }
        public double VVTRGVD { get; set; }
        public double IGVRGVD { get; set; }
        public double TOTRGVD { get; set; }
        public string PACEST { get; set; }

        public string CODUNI { get; set; }

        public string DIRCLI { get; set; }
        public string TELCLI { get; set; }
        public int PFLAG { get; set; }


        //I have to add the following, so generators are useless :(


        public RGVCAFAC()
        {
        }

        public RGVCAFAC(RGVCAFAC x)
        {
            this.CODEAUX = x.CODEAUX;
            this.FECRGV = x.FECRGV;
            this.TDORGV = x.TDORGV;
            this.MONRGV = x.MONRGV;
            this.RUCCLI = x.RUCCLI;
            this.RAZCLI = x.RAZCLI;
            this.CDCRGV = x.CDCRGV;
            this.TERRGV = x.TERRGV;
            this.PDSRGV = x.PDSRGV;
            this.VVTRGVS = x.VVTRGVS;
            this.IGVRGVS = x.IGVRGVS;
            this.TOTRGVS = x.TOTRGVS;
            this.TCARGV = x.TCARGV;
            this.VVTRGVD = x.VVTRGVD;
            this.IGVRGVD = x.IGVRGVD;
            this.TOTRGVD = x.TOTRGVD;
            this.PACEST = x.PACEST;
            this.CODUNI = x.CODUNI;
            this.DIRCLI = x.DIRCLI;
            this.TELCLI = x.TELCLI;
            this.PFLAG = x.PFLAG;
        }
    }
```

and finally :

```
var yourSequence = _grouppedResto.
                    Select((value, index) => new RGVCAFAC(value) { index = index+1, rgvcafac = value }).ToList(); //need to begin on 1 not on 0
                dgvCabecera.DataSource = yourSequence;
```

Comment: If someone find another way, please dont doubt to post it, I could mark it as an answer, for other people with the same cue

Answer (score 0):

```
int theIndex = 1;

foreach(var x in _grouppedResto)
{
  x.index = theIndex;
  theIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responses, Im already using that snippet, but Im looking for a LINQ solution.