# LINQ: Add RowNumber Column

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can the query below be modified to include a column for row number (ie: one-based index of results)?

```
var myResult = from currRow in someTable
               where currRow.someCategory == someCategoryValue
               orderby currRow.createdDate descending
               select currRow;
```

EDIT1: I'm looking for the results to be `{idx, col1, col2...col-n}` not `{idx, row}`.

EDIT2: The row number should correspond to result rows not the table rows.

EDIT3: I `DataBind` these results to a `GridView`.  My goal was to add a row number column to the `GridView`.  Perhaps a different approach would be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add an index field to Linq results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results)

Comment: Do you want the index of the row in the table or the index of the filtered result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding index to linq query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999365/adding-index-to-linq-query-result)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the method-syntax where [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) has an overload with the index:

```
var myResult = someTable.Select((r, i) => new { Row = r, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Row.someCategory == someCategoryValue)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Row.createdDate);
```

Note that this approach presumes that you want the original index of the row in the table and not in the filtered result since i select the index before i filter with `Where`.

> EDIT: I'm looking for the results to be {idx, col1, col2...col-n} not
>   {idx, row}. The row number should correspond to result rows not
>   the table rows.

Then select the anonymous type with all columns you need:

```
var myResult = someTable.Where(r => r.someCategory == someCategoryValue)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.createdDate)
        .Select((r, i) => new { idx = i, col1 = r.col1, col2 = r.col2, ...col-n = r.ColN });
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which unbundles the currRow. (see main post edit)

Comment: @Steven: Edited my answer. You can use an anonymous type.

Comment: @Steven: You can databind this result to a GridView. What problem did you have?

Comment: Problem solved.  I found a way to create a row number column in two different ways (1) adding index via LINQ or (2) adding a `TemplateField` `ItemTemplate` of `Container.DataItemIndex + 1`.

... I believe my actual problem is my spotty, learn-as-you-go knowledge of .NET.  I should probably go back and learn .NET with some structured training.

Comment: I'm new to Linq query, So here in order to retrieve all the columns including the newly added row number.What modification need to be done(if there are 10 columns or more specifying each will be hard)

Answer (score 6):

Use this [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method:

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index.

Example:

```
var myResult = someTable.Where(currRow => currRow.someCategory == someCategoryValue)
                        .OrderByDescending(currRow => currRow.createdDate)
                        .Select((currRow, index) => new {Row = currRow, Index = index + 1});
```

---

In response to your edit:

If you want a `DataTable` as result, you can go the non-Linq way by simply using a `DataView` and add a additional column afterwards.

```
someTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("someCategory = '{0}'", someCategoryValue);
someTable.DefaultView.Sort = "createdDate";
var resultTable = someTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
resultTable.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in resultTable.Rows)
    row["Number"] = ++i;
```

Comment: Presumes that OP wants the index of the rows after the filter was applied and not the index of the row in the table.

Answer (score 4):

what about?

```
int i;
var myResult = from currRow in someTable
           where currRow.someCategory == someCategoryValue
           orderby currRow.createdDate descending
           select new {Record = i++, currRow};
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's an alternative to `Select` with two arguments:

```
var resultsWithIndexes = myResult.Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue - 1),
                                      (o, i) => new { Index = i, Result = o });
```

Comment: @Steven: How are you going to use these new results? Do you have a type with the corresponding structure?

Comment: I will DataBind the results to a GridView.  I'm trying to add a row number column to the GridView.

Answer (score 3):

According to you edit 1. **NO, YOU CAN'T** Linq returns the table as it is. You can build each column, but you lose the power of mapped entities.

This has been asked multiple times before:  [How do you add an index field to Linq results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results)

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way if want to keep a flat list of columns (i.e. OP's Edit2) and also want a generic solution that works with any IEnumerable without requiring you to list out the set of expected columns.

However, there is a roundabout way to kinda go about it which is to dump the query results into a DataTable using the ToDataTable() method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817322/959296) and then add a RowNumber column to that table.

```
var table = query.ToList().ToDataTable();
table.Columns.Add("RowNum", typeof(int));
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    row["RowNum"] = ++i;
```

This would likely cause performance issues with large datasets but it's not insanely slow either. On my machine a dataset with ~6500 rows took 33ms to process.

If your original query returned an anonymous type, then that type definition will get lost in the conversion so you'll lose the static typing on the column names of the resulting IEnumerable when you call table.AsEnumerable(). In other words, instead of being able to write something like table.AsEnumerable().First().RowNum you instead have to write table.AsEnumerable().First()["RowNum"]

However, if you don't care about performance and really want your static typing back, then you can use JSON.NET to convert the DataTable to a json string and then back to a list based on the anonymous type from the original query result. This method requires a placeholder RowNum field to be present in the original query results.

```
var query  = (from currRow in someTable
            where currRow.someCategory == someCategoryValue
            orderby currRow.createdDate descending
            select new { currRow.someCategory, currRow.createdDate, RowNum = -1 }).ToList();
var table = query.ToDataTable();
//Placeholder RowNum column has to already exist in query results
//So not adding a new column, but merely populating it
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    row["RowNum"] = ++i;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
var staticallyTypedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, query);
Console.WriteLine(staticallyTypedList.First().RowNum);
```

This added about 120ms to the processing time for my 6500 item dataset.

It's crazy, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I wanted to show what worked for me.

I have a list of objects, and the object has an integer property on it for "row number"... or in this case, "Sequence Number".  This is what I did to populate that field:

```
myListOfObjects = myListOfObjects.Select((o, i) => { o.SequenceNumber = i; return o; }).ToList();
```

I was surprised to see that this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me in my case - Excel sheet extraction. anonymous type

```
var UploadItemList = ItemMaster.Worksheet().AsEnumerable().Select((x, index) => new
{
    Code = x["Code"].Value == null ? "" : x["Code"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    Description = x["Description"].Value == null ? "" : x["Description"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    Unit = x["Unit"].Value == null ? "" : x["Unit"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    Quantity = x["Quantity"].Value == null ? "" : x["Quantity"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    Rate = x["Rate"].Value == null ? "" : x["Rate"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    Amount = x["Amount"].Value == null ? "" : x["Amount"].Value.ToString().Trim(),
    RowNumber = index+1
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Lc = 1;

var Lst = LstItemGrid.GroupBy(item => item.CategoryName)
    .Select(group => new { CategoryName = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() ,RowIndex= Lc++ })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.