# Linq Include from List<string>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to specify "Includes" from a List please?

I have a list of possible sub tables to be included in:

```
List<string> includedTables
```

My current database call looks like this:

```
return db.SA_Items
       .Where(x => x.LastUpdated > lastUpdated)
       .Where(x => x.Active == true)
       .OrderBy(x => x.ItemID)
       .Skip(offset)
       .Take(limit)
       .ToList();
```

I would to somehow to a foreach string in the List and add a `.Include(....)` to the database call...

Say, for example, if there were 2 strings in the list the code would be equivalent to this:

```
return db.SA_Items
       .Include("first string in the list")
       .Include("second string in the list")
       .Where(x => x.LastUpdated > lastUpdated)
       .Where(x => x.Active == true)
       .OrderBy(x => x.ItemID)
       .Skip(offset)
       .Take(limit)
       .ToList();
```

It's also possible that the List might be null.

Is it possible to do this dynamically somehow?

Can anyone give me any pointers please?

Comment: @Fabjan, it must be to eager load related entities, that is the propose of `Include` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can build your query in several steps:

```
IQueryable<SA_Item> query=db.SA_Items;
if(includedTables!=null)
   query = includedTables.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

query=query.Where(x => x.LastUpdated > lastUpdated)
           .Where(x => x.Active == true)
           .OrderBy(x => x.ItemID)
           .Skip(offset)
           .Take(limit);
return query.ToList();// Materialize your query
```

Comment: I am getting the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<SADatastore.SA_Items>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SADatastore.SA_Items>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" on the current.Include(include) part... :(

Comment: That's make sense, use `IQueryable<T>` type instead a `var` to save your query. That should solve the issue.

Comment: really sorry, now it's saying "System.Linq.IQueryable<SADatastore.SA_Items>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SADatastore.SA_Items>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Add `System.Data.Entity` namespace

Answer (score 0):

You could do a similar thing which is happening in the following stackoverflow link, but replace the int index which has been added with your strings:

[LINQ: Add RowNumber Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960563/linq-add-rownumber-column)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with concat.

```
return db.SA_Items
       .Concat(new string[] {"first string in the list", "second string in the list"})
       .Where(x => x.LastUpdated > lastUpdated)
       .Where(x => x.Active == true)
       .OrderBy(x => x.ItemID)
       .Skip(offset)
       .Take(limit)
       .ToList();
```