# How I get RowNumber with Model In Entity Framework core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in MVC Core using EntityFramework. How can I get
the row number in view in the table?

My model is:

```
public class Provider{

        public int ProviderId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DateOfBirth{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Provider.ToListAsync());
        }
```

View Is:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Provider>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
                  <tr>
                <td>
                        #
                </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProviderId)
              
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
             </td>
    }
```

output:

```
100 | Foo | 10/10/1990|
101 | Bar | 10/10/1990|
```

I want a row number at the start, output like:

```
1|100 | Foo | 10/10/1990|
2|101 | Bar | 10/10/1990|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to have row numbers for your table, you can do it simply by changing your view to the following:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    int rowNumber = 1;
}
@model IEnumerable<Project.Provider>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @rowNumber
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProviderId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
        </tr>
        rowNumber++;
}
```

or if you want to do it with Linq, check out this question:
[LINQ: Add RowNumber Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960563/linq-add-rownumber-column)