# How to Add Rownum to GroupBy Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex LINQ Query to extract Top students in my university. Here is the query :

```
            var query = Db.Students.AsNoTracking().Where(...).AsQueryable();
            var resultgroup = query.GroupBy(st => new
                {
                    st.Student.CourseStudyId,
                    st.Student.EntranceTermId,
                    st.Student.StudyingModeId,
                    st.Student.StudyLevelId
                }, (key, g) => new
                {
                    CourseStudyId = key.CourseStudyId,
                    EntranceTermId = key.EntranceTermId,
                    StudyingModeId = key.StudyingModeId,
                    StudyLevelId = key.StudyLevelId,
                    list = g.OrderByDescending(x => 
                    x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm).Take(topStudentNumber)
                }).SelectMany(q => q.list).AsQueryable();
```

This Query give me top n students based on 4 parameters and on their TotalAverageTillTerm.

Now I want to add rownum for each group to simulate Total rank, for example Output is :

[image]

Now I want to Add TotalRank as rownumber like Sql. In the picture X1=1,X2=2,X3=3 and Y1=1,Y2=2,Y3=3

If I want to reduce problem. I only work on one group. Code Like this :

```
                resultgroup = query.GroupBy(st => new
                {
                    st.Student.StudyLevelId
                }, st => st, (key, g) => new
                {
                    StudyLevelId = key.StudyLevelId,
                    list = g.OrderByDescending(x => 
                    x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm)
                     .Take(topStudentNumber)
                }).SelectMany(q => q.list).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: It seems you want `TotalRank= g.Count()`?

Comment: isn't total rank the index of people in  list +1 : `list = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm).Take(topStudentNumber)
.Select((x,i) => new { prop1 = x.Prop1, rank = i+1 } )`

Comment: An [mre] may have help. Especially the minimal part. 
If you reduce the problem to only one grouped group of student the probleme would be reduce to "add a row number in linq", right? 
If it's the case then this will make a good [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960563/linq-add-rownumber-column)

Comment: I try select (x,i) but C# raise error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list was a List of student but I see no sign of student having a rank property so I wrapped it into a annonimous type with rank.

```
var query = Db.Students.AsNoTracking().Where(...).AsEnumerable();
var resultgroup = query.GroupBy(st => new   {
        st.Student.CourseStudyId,
        st.Student.EntranceTermId,
        st.Student.StudyingModeId,
        st.Student.StudyLevelId
    })
    .SelectMany( g =>       
        g.OrderByDescending(x =>x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm)
                .Take(topStudentNumber)
                .Select((x,i) => new { 
                    CourseStudyId = g.Key.CourseStudyId,
                    EntranceTermId = g.Key.EntranceTermId,
                    StudyingModeId = g.Key.StudyingModeId,
                    StudyLevelId = g.Key.StudyLevelId,
                    Rank = i+1                  
                    //studentPorperty = x.Prop1, 
                })
    )
    .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: If that work we can all admit that the question is a dupe: of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960563/linq-add-rownumber-column. And we simply fail to isolate the issue first hand.

Comment: Hey your answer give me row num foreach group. I dont want it. I want to add rownum inside of each group. that means if i have one group with 3 students, it give me 1,2,3. but your answer give me only 1 for this group

Comment: if i use  

foreach (var item in resultgroup){
                        print item.List , Item.rank
}
you know that it is wrong

Comment: Item as a sub list was your design choice btw. So there is no `item.List , Item.rank`, use auto competion or debug to explore the item if you are lost. I have flattern the Select for something I think more easy. Use the edit history if it doesn't suit.  Btw. Im out. Please refere to [mre] and [ask]. It's been working on my side since 30min. Not my job .

Comment: Oh you change your code. ill try and send you feedback

Comment: I try your code but it is not work. give me error :
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType247`5[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Int32]] Select[StudentTerm,<>f__AnonymousType247`5](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Hamava.Model.Education.StudentTerm], System.Func`3[Hamava.Model.Education.StudentTerm,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType247`5[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Int32]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @mahdimoghimi, see that `AsQueryable` at the top swap it to `.AsEnumerable()`. Don't know what AsQueryable does there but enumerable to load the student and do the group by in memeory. no need to translate projecttion code to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean :

```
   var query = Db.Students.AsNoTracking().Where(...).AsQueryable();
   var resultgroup = query.GroupBy(st => new
                {
                    st.Student.CourseStudyId,
                    st.Student.EntranceTermId,
                    st.Student.StudyingModeId,
                    st.Student.StudyLevelId
                }, (key, g) => new
                    {
                        CourseStudyId = key.CourseStudyId,
                        EntranceTermId = key.EntranceTermId,
                        StudyingModeId = key.StudyingModeId,
                        StudyLevelId = key.StudyLevelId,
                        list = g.OrderByDescending(x => 
                        x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm)
                        .Take(topStudentNumber)
                        .Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, TotalRank = i /* item number inside group */}),
                        StudentsInGroupCount = g.Count() // count group this items
                    }).SelectMany(q => q).AsQueryable();
```

To see the results :

```
foreach (var item in resultgroup.ToList())
{
    item.list.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.TotalRank));
}
```

Comment: If I Add total rank Where Can I use it?
how can I use it in SelectMany?

Comment: try this :

.SelectMany(q => q).AsQueryable(); so you have all the info that you want

Comment: I do but it only give me rank of each group. for example student1,2,3 have rank 1, student 4,5,6 = rank2 ...

Comment: Select index

list = g.OrderByDescending(x => 
                        x.StudentTermSummary.TotalAverageTillTerm).Take(topStudentNumber).Select((x, i) => new { item, i })

Comment: it give me error  : the type argument for method .... cannot be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments expelicitly

Comment: hey. list give me for example to 3 or top n student for each group. so you must work on it not outside of it. I want to create rownum inside of each group. your solution give me rownum outside of each group

Comment: Yes that on is from the GroupBy overload you choose. Instead of the simple with only the grouping key you took the one with key+ projection. If you drop that part into a proper select it will work.

Comment: its not work for this solution.  your answer give me row num foreach group. I dont want it. I want to add rownum inside of each group. that means if i have one group with 3 students, it give me 1,2,3. but your answer give me only 1 for this group if i use foreach (var item in resultgroup){ print item.List , Item.rank } you know that it is wrong

Comment: Thanks but in console.writeline I want to show rowNum. could you please change your code to write each group and their rownumber inside of each group

Comment: Check current one

Comment: I try your code, it raise me error  : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType247`5[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Int32]] Select[StudentTerm,<>f__AnonymousType247`5](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Hamava.Model.Education.StudentTerm], System.Func`3[Hamava.Model.Education.StudentTerm,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType247`5[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Guid,System.Int32]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Are you using .Net Core 3.1 ? If so you  can do the query locally but it may have effect on performance
To do this change this to :
   var query = await Db.Students.AsNoTracking().Where(...).ToListAsync();

And chanege :
foreach (var item in resultgroup)

Comment: I use .net not core

Comment: Try to get the data from db ( ToList or ToListAsync ) and the do the groupby query on the list