# Concatenate string from array and include it's index C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, csv, concatenation

Consider the following csv

```
string data = "Hey, Bob, How are you";
```

I can flatten it to:

```
"Hey; Bob; How are you"
```

Using the following:

```
var s = String.Join("; ",data.Split(',').Select(d => d.Trim()).ToArray());
```

Is there any way I can get the index of the current item in the join and append it to the resulting string? To produce somthing along the lines of:

```
"Hey=0; Bob=1; How are you=2"
```

Does linq facilitate anything like this? Perhaps combined with a String.Format() type method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an index field to Linq results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here try this there is an index selector in the select you can use it to concatonate with each of your data pieces

```
var s = String.Join("; ",data.Split(',')
                  .Select((d, i) => d.Trim() + "= " + i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Sure - just change your `Select` slightly:

```
var s = String.Join("; ",data.Split(',')
                             .Select((d, i) => String.Format("{0}={1}",d.Trim(),i)));
```

note that `string.Join` can take an `IEnumerable<T>` so there's no need to call `ToArray`.

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks, fixed.

Comment: NP, I was racing to get my answer in too, thats why I used the plus, but the string format is more efficient especially since it will be occuring multiple times