# Yield return from an indexed iteration via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Leaving the performance cost of LINQ usage, I would like to know how to convert the following code into a LINQ expression

```
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length(); i++)
  yield return new SomeEntity(someFunction(i));
```

Important: I need the use of the incremented index

---

Update:

Rather than `someArray.length()`, `number` should be used:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
  yield return new SomeEntity(someFunction(i));
```

---

2nd update

I'm still getting the compilation error "not all code paths return value"

My code:

```
public static IEnumerable function()
{
    Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i => new Entity());
}
```

3rd update

---

Didn't think it's relevant until I found out it's the cause for this error..

```
public static IEnumerable function()
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    foreach (int i in arr)
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i => new Entity());
    }
}
```

If you take out the foreach 1st loop out of the equation, all replies answer to this question, but my issue is n^2..   2 nested loops...

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an index field to Linq results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results)

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions to make existing answer invalid. You should instead add an update at the end of the existing question.

Answer (score 6):

Use the overload of `Enumerable.Select` that has an index into the collection:

```
someArray.Select((x, i) => new SomeEntity(someFunction(i)));
```

#### Edit

As you've modified your example and are not actually using a collection to iterate and index to, use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, number).Select(i => new SomeEntity(someFunction(i)));
```

Comment: this is an inner loop where, someArray.length() is actually an Xpath function generating a node count, so basically someArray.Length() is just a number :/   editting it to the OQ

Comment: @USS-Montana I've edited my answer to reflect your new question.

Comment: I'm getting an error - not all code paths return a value, tried it with this example, Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => 1);

Comment: @USS-Montana - You need `return` in front of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate the numbers:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,number).Select(i=>new SomeEntity(someFunction(i)));
```

Comment: I'm getting an error - not all code paths return a value, tried it with this example, Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => 1);

Comment: @USS-Montana - then how about showing us more than two lines of code and expecting us to divine the context and fix bugs in code we cannot see?

Comment: @USS-Montana - You need `return` in front of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my LinqPad snippet.

```
void Main()
{

    var e = SomeEntity.GetEntities(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3});
    e.Dump();
}

public class SomeEntity
{
    public int m_i;
    public SomeEntity(int i)
    {
        m_i = i;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_i.ToString();
    }


    public static int someFunction(int i){ return i+100;}

    public static IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetEntities(IEnumerable<int> someArray)
    {
//        for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Count();i++)
//            yield return new SomeEntity(someFunction(i));

        // *** Equivalent linq function ***    
        return someArray.Select(a => new SomeEntity(someFunction(a)));    
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally found the problem!!

Comment: my linq for loop is nested inside a foreach loop,  and if I add this to your code you'l get a similar problem

Comment: int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            foreach (int i in arr)
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(a => new SomeEntity(someFunction(a)));
            }