# how do I select first ischecked property of list to true and rest false

Tags: c#, linq

How do I select first ischecked property of list to true and rest false.

```
unitnames_list = (from DataRow row in dt_get_unitnames.Rows
                  select new tb_units
                  {
                      UnitID = Convert.ToInt32(row["UnitID"].ToString()),
                      UnitName = row["UnitName"].ToString(),
                      ischecked = true
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: `ischecked = false`, then `unitnames_list[0].ischecked = false;`

Comment: thanks bro .it solved my issue

Comment: And I assume you corrected my typo - `unitnames_list[0].ischecked = true;` (not `false`) :)

Comment: ya I did that..

Answer (score 1):

Following [How do you add an index field to Linq results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results), one possible solution would be

```
unitnames_list = dt_get_unitnames.Rows.Select((row, index) =>
    new tb_units
    {
        UnitID = Convert.ToInt32(row["UnitID"].ToString()),
        UnitName = row["UnitName"].ToString(),
        ischecked = index == 0
    }).ToList();
```